# NextJS 12 - CSS Compiler Return Undefined mixin

Tags: webpack, next.js

I've update my project to NextJS 12.
and when I start `npm run dev` It returns error like below:

```
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[9].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[9].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[9].use[3]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/sass-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[9].use[4]!./src/assets/scss/style.scss
SassError: Undefined mixin.
    ╷
318 │     @include border-top-left-radius($card-border-radius);
    │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  src/assets/scss/components/_card.scss 318:5  @import
  src/assets/scss/style.scss 20:5              root stylesheet
```

I want to give you more feedback actually, but nothing more. I've tried to delete and reinstall node-modules etc.

Comment: Where is the `border-top-left-radius` mixin defined?

Comment: this is default bootstrap including

Comment: Where are you including Bootstrap styles in your project? Can you share the code you have in `style.scss`?